# How to pick a selected option from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I have a select box like this:

```
    <select name="id_category" id="">
        <?php foreach($categorys as $category): ?>
            <option value="<?= $category['id']?>"><?= $category['name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach?>
    </select>
```

There are three categorys: Residential, Comercial and Institutional.

How can I put it in a way that it already appears in the current selected category?

Answer (score 0):

Having the selected category:

```
<option <? echo $selected == $category['id'] ? "selected " : "" ?>....
```